# Are Mastercoin addresses Bitcoin addresses?

Tags: omni

I am reading up on Mastercoin, and I must say, it is quite confusing. Am I correct in saying that your Bitcoin address *is* your Mastercoin Address? If so, I have one private key that contains two cryptocurrencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, that's right - Mastercoin uses the same address space as Bitcoin.

You can store BTC, MSC, TMSC (Test MSC), and soon many other crypto-currencies on the same address using The Master Protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: [www.youtube.com/watch?v=mAW-kuoZaHU](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mAW-kuoZaHU) and you'll probably understand how it works.

You download the blockchain with Bitcoin-QT and run my Mastercoins wallet through it.You label the addresses in your QT wallet and you can now send BTC and MSC to these addresses.

Comment: link not working.. :(